# How do I get a Java object's fields?

Tags: java, object, key, field

I have a Java object that looks something like this:

```
{
  "-MkZ12sdf23":{title:"Math"},
  "-MkZsadfdfdfg":{title:"Chemistry"}
}
```

The first fields are randomly generated IDs, so I cannot just get the titles like

```
object.-MkZ12sdf23.title
```

How can I get each fields' title and store them in a variable or an object?

Comment: do you mean json objects?
Also where is this data coming from that might help to give us a reference on how to deal with it

Comment: Yes, it is a JSON object coming from Firebase Realtime Database. Is there a way I could "skip" the ID fields directly to the title field?

Comment: you will need to work with the apis that are provided by the database you are working with. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write this link is for realtime databases as well as https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data is for firestore also there is a link which is mentioned when this question was closed.